# Merging(?) Smaller DataFrame into bigger DataFrame (Pandas/Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am running a process where I am trying to merge some predicted values back into another dataframe which has the 'actual' values.

The problem I'm having is that after the `merge` is done, I end up with a new dataframe that only has 1 row. In this case, I am wanting to update the `predicted_sales` column in the parent dataframe to the value in `yhat` if the date matches.

Is it possible to take a smaller dataframe (in this case, a dataframe with 1 record) and marge it into a larger dataframe (n records) without having to go through and iterate on every row and see if a value should be upated?

I thought I was on the right path with `pd.merge` but it's not looking right:

```
result_df = pd.merge(orig_df, sales_forecast_df, on='date')
```

[image]

Comment: try passing `how='outer'` in your `merge`

Comment: result_df = pd.merge(orig_df, sales_forecast_df, on='date',how='left')

Comment: Looks like there is no match between date values of both dataframes, outer merge will keep all rows but introduce NaNs where it does not find corresponding value

Comment: @roganjosh that did it!

Comment: Just like @vaishali said, I do end up with NaN in the rest of the values. In my case, that's fine though.

Comment: I've re-read and I might be unclear on what you're trying to do. You only ever want that single item from the original df to be updated? Merge is _really_ expensive for that unless `outer` is the kind of thing you were looking for

Comment: Ah nm, we got there then :)

Comment: @roganjosh will mark as answer if you make your comment an answer